# Get url of uploaded pdf file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a new custom field on post page whose type is "file" and its slug is "pdf_file". I want to get url of uploaded pdf file form post. I have tried
by using the following code.

```
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdf_file', true);
```

AND

```
$my_meta = wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
```

Comment: Are you using any plugin ? can i see your file upload code ? you might have any path specified in the file upload code ?

Comment: @Poria  yes i am using advance custom field plugin.

Comment: @Poria i am uploading the file form admin panel, add_new_post page.

Comment: Did you try as per ACF documentation here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-media-attachment/

Comment: or may be https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-field-plugin-get-file-url

Comment: @Poria thanks i have get the pdf url

Comment: please mark my comments as useful if it helped !